# Firefox redirects back to previous page - Wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, url, firefox, redirect

I'm having a really bad issue here and I can't find anything about it online... this is my website:
http://top6.com

when you try to go to a page from FireFox, it shows you the page then redirects you back to the previous one... this only happens with FireFox and only happens if I'm not in a Private window. I tried to disable all plugins I have installed, didn't work. Checked htaccess, seems fine... Checkev for malware - none. Don't know what else to do... any help is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

The same issue for me. I can say precisely that firefox go to the referer.
For instance from google to post, firefox go first to post then redirect to google (the referer).

When i test http://top6.com i see no redirection. Could you test for seeyar.fr?
Regards.
Nota: no problem with chrome or edge

Comment: Yes, I saw the issue on your website... It is exactly the same. After many hours of researches I figured it must be something from the ads. I see you have AdSense on your website too. I think they cause the issue, because when you turn adblocker on, the issue disappears. The problem is I'm not sure how to remove the ads... deleted every ad script I found in the php. files of the theme, but they still keep showing up...

Answer (score 0):

I found this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1244326
there is a relation with cloudflare (rocket ) and the redirection.
So Wait and see.

Rgrds,